# Intellij multi-module project - Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am working on a project which has multiple modules like client, common, server. 
In  the server module of the project I have a service which is referencing to a new class I created in the common module. 
For some reason, when I run the project locally, I repeatedly get this error ->

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin ....   cannot find symbol 
[ERROR] symbol : class Document
```

for the new Document class I added in the common module.

When I Build -> Rebuild my common module and server module again, the error goes away. 
But when this happens, it fails during runtime with ClassNotFoundException
I am running project with mvn spring-boot:run command

Is there a permanent fix for this?

I think I need to fix the structure of project or add the right dependency in the settings.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say _I am running project with mvn spring-boot:run command_, do you mean, it runs fine with command line Maven and the error only present in Idea?

Comment: the error shows when I run in commandline, actually mvn install fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran mvn install for the common module and it fixed all problems. Thanks.